# Kendo UI, searchable Combobox

Tags: jquery, combobox, kendo-ui, kendo-combobox

I am using the free Kendo UI Core Framework. I am looking for a searchable Combobox that fires the sql after inserting, for example, 2 letters. Behind my Listbox there are more than 10000 items and now it takes too much time when I load or refresh the page.

Is it possible to trigger the sql query only by user input like the autocomplete widget do?

My code is:

```
<link href="test/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="test/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="test/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="test/js/kendo.ui.core.min.js"></script>

 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {

 var objekte = $("#objekte").kendoComboBox({
 placeholder: "Objekt auswählen",
 dataTextField: "kurzname",
 dataValueField: "objekt_id",
 minLength: 2,
 delay: 0,

 dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
      read: "test/objects.php"
    },

    schema: {
        data: "data"
    }

 }),
 }).data("kendoComboBox");
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set [`autoBind`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/combobox#configuration-autoBind) to `false` in order to do not automatically load everything from the server at bind (initialisation) time.

Then, combine it with [`minLength`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/combobox#configuration-minLength) in order to specify the minimum number of characters that the user should type.

Finally, set [`serverFiltering`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/datasource#configuration-serverFiltering) to `true` in order to bring only the elements that meet the condition.

Check this demo from Kendo UI web site: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/combobox/serverfiltering.html

Answer (score 0):

now it works !

```
 var objekte = $("#maytest1objekt").kendoComboBox({
 placeholder: "Objekt auswählen",
 dataTextField: "kurzname",
 dataValueField: "objekt_id",

 serverFiltering: true,
 filter: "startswith",
 autoBind: false,
 minLength: 1,
 delay: 0,

 dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
      read: "test/objects.php"
    },
    schema: {
        data: "data"
    }
 }),
 }).data("kendoComboBox");
```